# Finding Spherical Coordinates from Non-Zero point on Sphere

Tags: geometry

for arguments sake, let's say I'm trying to find spherical coordinates from say (45,90) (latitude,longitude) on the earth, and then convert that result back into cartesian coordinates.  I realize this seems counterintuitive since I already have the exact coordinates, but I do not have the coordinates relative to the location.  What I want to be able to do is find the location on the planet setting (45,90) as the zero of the spherical axis so that I can then convert it back to cartesian coordinates and get the exact location.  Is there some kind of transformation I'm overlooking which makes this possible?

Comment: The earth is better modeled by an ellipsoid. Depending on the accuracy you need this is an important consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Up to factors of $\frac {\pi}{180}$ and the direction of measurement, latitude and longitude are spherical coordinates.  If we assume a spherical earth, you have the coordinates.  The radius is $R_e$ the radius of the earth.  $\theta$, the polar angle is $90^\circ$ minus the latitude.  $\phi$, the azimuthal angle is the longitude.  You can convert it to Cartesian by the usual approach:  $x=R_e \sin \theta \cos \phi$ and so on.

Comment: I must have not explained myself very clearly.  As I did state, I realize how to get any coordinates from the spherical system, what I want to know how to do is translate the zero of the spherical coordinate system relative to the cartesian system.  Because if for example I had two points on the sphere and I used each of them as zeros for the spherical coordinate system, the arc of each one would not align with the arc of the other, and that is my problem.

Comment: The zero of both the Cartesian and spherical systems is at the center of the earth.  The point at latitude 0, longitude 0 on the surface of the earth has coordinates $(R_e,0,0)$ in the Cartesian system and $(R_e,90^\circ,0)$ in the spherical if you use the usual spherical angles measuring $\theta$ down from the $z$ axis.